# Passive construction with two clause

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I have to make passive construction of these sentences.

1 I expected my father to give me financial aid during crisis.

Passive 1: My father was expected to give financial aid during crisis. (My answer but book says it's incorrect)

Passive 2: A financial aid during crisis was expected to give by my father.

Why my answer is incorrect?

2 People claim that he left the country two month ago.

Passive 1: It is claimed that he left the country two month ago.

Passive 2: He is claimed to have left the country two month ago.

As in 2 question there are two passive construction. So In question 1 My answer should also be correct.

In #3 and #4, I want to know if both Passive formation are correct. There is difference in placement of phrase.

3 Sirosky has published all the experience that he had on the space station.

Passive 1: All the experience **that he had on the space station** have been published by Sirosky. (Book answer)

Passive 2: All the experience have been published by Sirosky **that he had on the space station**. (my answer)

4 Has anybody forecast the flood situation in Bihar?

Passive 1: Has the flood situation **in Bihar** been forecast? (Book answer)

Passive 2: Has the flood situation been forecast **in Bihar**? (My answer)

Thank you

Comment: What is the question?  If there are more than one verb in a sentence, then there may be more than one passive construction.  You have told us the answer that "the book" says is "wrong" but you haven't told us the question. The quote "active" sentences contain (minor) errors. Please [edit] to ask one clear question, and to ensure that you have made no mistakes when copying.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please now clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question has been edited, it remains very unclear. It appears that the original exercise was a multiple choice exercise, but it is not clear whether only two choices were given. Nor is it always clear which choice the textbook asserted to be correct. For this question to be useful to other learners, further, and major, editing is required, but such editing may be beyond the powers of the OP. Consequently, I shall try to help the OP with an answer despite the fogginess of the question.

With respect to the first exercise, the original sentence is not grammatical (missing article before "crisis," which is a countable noun). The first proposed answer is grammatical except for the error in the original sentence, but loses information contained in the original sentence, namely who was expecting and who was to receive. It is unclear whether the main verb "expected" was to be made passive, the infinitive "to give" was to be made passive, or both changes were to be made. Any of the following would be grammatical while retaining all information from the original sentence: "It was expected by me that my father would give me financial aid ..." or "I expected to be given financial aid by my father ..." or "It was expected by me that I would be given financial aid by my father ...". Only the second of those possibilities is graceful English. The second proposed answer is very bad English. If that is what the textbook recommends, you need a different textbook **immediately**.

With respect to the second exercise, the first proposed answer is perfectly grammatical. Absent better understanding of the exercise, I see no reason for it to be considered an unacceptable answer. The second proposed answer is not grammatical.

With respect to the third exercise, neither proposed answer is grammatical. The first would be grammatical if the subject were "experiences" rather than "experience." The second is not grammatical because the restrictive clause is too far separated from its referrant.

With respect to the fourth exercise, the book answer is correct. The alternative answer changes the meaning from the situation in Bihar to the location of the forecast. Again the modifying phrase has been shifted in position so that it modifies "forecast" rather than "flood situation."

Comment: [yes it is an exercise with multiple choice answers]

Comment: Two possibilities or more?

Comment: Its objective type exercise with 4 answers given but only one is correct.

Comment: When you are to choose one from four options, but you disclose to us only two, it is impossible for us to tell you which of the four is best and why.

Comment: Yes sir I mention the answer where I have a confusion and  leaves the options which are obviously wrong.

Comment: Well in that case, what have I not already answered?

Comment: you cleared my doubt about my question.